Failed to run model, Interpreter busy, java.lang.RuntimeException: Interpreter busy
I am working on a flutter app for object detection with tensorflow tflite model when I run the application I get the error:

I/flutter ( 6447): Error running model on frame: PlatformException(Failed to run model, Interpreter busy, java.lang.RuntimeException: Interpreter busy
I/flutter ( 6447):      at sq.flutter.tflite.TflitePlugin$TfliteTask.(TflitePlugin.java:486)
I/flutter ( 6447):      at sq.flutter.tflite.TflitePlugin$RunModelOnFrame.(TflitePlugin.java:581)
I/flutter ( 6447):      at sq.flutter.tflite.TflitePlugin.onMethodCall(TflitePlugin.java:151)
I/flutter ( 6447):      at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:267)
I/flutter ( 6447):      at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.invokeHandler(DartMessenger.java:292)
I/flutter ( 6447):      at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.lambda$dispatchMessageToQueue$0$io-flutter-embedding-engine-dart-DartMessenger(DartMessenger.java:319)

and I am using the package tflite_v2: ^1.0.0
so how to fix this ?
and can it be caused by the model I am using ?
is there a specific tensorflow model for flutter or all tflite models can be used ?
